# How to use Executors as an alternative for AsyncTask to fetch data from a database in android?

Tags: android, executor

I need to fetch user data from database in android. But AsyncTask is deprecated in API level 30. Executors is used as an alternative for AsyncTask. But I don't know how to use it to fetch data from database and return it to the Activity. Can someone please show me how to fetch user data using Executors.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use the Executor from the Repository and return the data to the ViewModel. But I am unable to return the data from the run method. The runOnUiThread helped me to update the UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Executors like this :

For Multi Threading :

```
private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE);
```

For Single Thread :

```
private final ExecutorService  service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Now simply execute your work using execute() function like this :

```
service.execute(new Runnable{

  // Fetch user data here or do whatever you want to do on background thread.
  // This is same as doInBackground method of AsyncTask which executes on the background thread.

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable{

    //This Section will Execute on Main thread.
    // Use this if you want to access any UI element.
  });


});
```

Just remember to shutdown the Executor when you are finished like this :

```
service.shutdown();  --> initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted
```

OR

```
service.shutdownNow();  --> stop all actively executing tasks
```

Comment: Thanks @DrHowdyDoo. This helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Previous AsyncTask<> functionality can be simply achieved by following way:
Create a TaskRunner Class like this:

```
public class TaskRunner {
private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); // change according to your requirements
private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

public interface Callback<R> {
    void onComplete(R result);
}

public <R> void executeAsync(Callable<R> callable, Callback<R> callback) {
    executor.execute(() -> {
        final R result = callable.call();
        handler.post(() -> {
            callback.onComplete(result);
        });
    });
}
```

}

Pass input parameters like this:

```
class LongRunningTask implements Callable<MyPojo> {
    private final String input;

    public LongRunningTask(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public MyPojo call() {
        // Some long running task
        return myPojo;
    }
}
```

And use the result like this:

```
// in Activity
   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


    //start loading progress or whatever you wish...
     TaskRunner taskRunner = new TaskRunner();
    taskRunner.executeAsync(new LongRunningTask(input), (data) -> {
    
      //hide progress bar on response;
      // Use data variable to load your UI
      // note: data is of type MyPojo

    });

}
```